# SVN server not working since upgrade to Debian 9

Tags: debian, svn, debian-stretch

I my Subversion server stopped working about the time when I upgraded the server to Debian 9. It gives me:

```
svn ci -m "Updates"
svn: E170013: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://svn.mydomain.com/svn/trunk/websites'
svn: E000111: Error running context: Connection refused
```

The server is up:

```
ping svn.mydomain.com
PING svn (172.16.11.128) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from svn (172.16.11.128): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.426 ms
64 bytes from svn (172.16.11.128): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.254 ms
```

And I can SSH into it. Firewall on the server is disabled:

```
root@svn:~# ufw status
Status: inactive
```

I have WebSVN but I cannot access the repositories in the browser either. I can't telnet either:

```
telnet svn.mydomain.com 3690
Trying 172.16.11.128...
telnet: connect to address 172.16.11.128: Connection refused
```

I am trying to connect from Fedora 26. Also tried to access the repo via WebSVN from an Android phone but still no success.

Does anybody knows what is going on here?